# Share button in GameScene

Tags: ios, button, sprite-kit, share

Can someone help me by telling me how to add a share option into my GameScene? I have a button which is a SKSpriteNode but I can not set it up so it will open the share option for Facebook, Twitter etd.
I am trying to present a viewcontroller which is the activityViewController but it does not work in the gameScene. Can anyone help with this please? thanks in advance!
Also I do not know how to hide and unhide a UIbutton in the GameScene. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in GameScene put this in your touchesBegan method

**NOTE-** that shareBtn is `var shareBtn = SKSpriteNode()`

```
for touch in touches {
        if isDead == true {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if shareBtn.contains(location) {

                if var top = scene?.view?.window?.rootViewController {
                    while let presentedViewController = top.presentedViewController {
                        top = presentedViewController
                    }
                    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Can you beat my Score of \(score) in Crappy Duck?"], applicationActivities: nil)
                    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
                    top.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i dont really know why this works i got it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821684/gamescene-share-button)